# Изменить всплывающее меню в окне Windows PyQt5

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, gui, qmainwindow

У меня есть небольшой графический интерфейс на *PyQt5*. При нажатии на иконку главного окна в левом верхнем углу открывается меню. 
Я так понимаю, это стандартное меню для всех окон в *Windows*.

Я хочу переопределить это меню - добавить один пункт - "О программе", при нажатии на который будет открываться диалоговое окно с некоторой информацией.

Как я могу это сделать?

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # конфигурация главного окна
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1500, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Чтение БКУ')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_main_window = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout_main_window)
        
        # конфигурация верхней панели инструментов
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addStretch(1)
        self.btn_start_reading = QPushButton("Считать")
        self.btn_download_from_file = QPushButton("Загрузить из файла")
        self.btn_save_to_file = QPushButton("Экспорт")
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_start_reading)
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_download_from_file)
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_save_to_file)
        self.layout_main_window.addLayout(self.layout_toolbar_buttons)

        # конфигурация таблицы
        self.layout_table = QHBoxLayout()
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(9)
        self.table.setRowCount(13500)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['№', 'Дата и время', 'БКУ', 'КЛ', 'АУ', 'Канал', 'Код события', 'Доп. параметр', 'Описание'])
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        for col in range(8):
            self.table.setColumnWidth(col, 130)
        self.layout_table.addWidget(self.table)
        self.layout_main_window.addLayout(self.layout_table)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPDATE**:

У меня есть программа на *С#*, которая делает аналогичное действие. К сожалению, я не знаю *С#* и не знаю, насколько это поможет, но прикладываю участок кода, который, как мне кажется, отвечает за добавление нового пункта в меню, всплывающее при нажатии на иконку.

```cs
protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
{
    if (msg.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
    {
        switch (msg.WParam.ToInt32())
        {
            case MYMENU1:
                AboutProgram aboutProgram=new AboutProgram();
                aboutProgram.ShowDialog();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref msg);
}

private void AddMainContext()
{
    IntPtr MenuHandle = GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, false);
    InsertMenu(MenuHandle, 5, MF_BYPOSITION, MYMENU1, "О программе");
}
```

Comment: В Вашем приведенном примере на `C#` больше `WinAPI` чем `С#` примерно так же код выглядел бы и на `C++` и даже на `макроассемблере`, я не пытаюсь запугать, просто намекаю на то что для подобной реализации понадобится привлекать целую артелерию. `QT` по своей сути берет на себя обязанности по созданию окна и маршрутизации событий если Вам нужно вмешаться в его работу то это потребует понимания как это реализовать именно на `WinAPI` и как его вызовы сделать на `Python`, понятно что задача со **"звездочкой"** но меня все равно смущает целесообразность данной затеи.

Answer (score 1):

Для windows можно так реализовать:

```
...
import win32gui
import win32.lib.win32con as win32con

...
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.custom_menu_id = 6

        hwnd = self.winId()
        hmenu = win32gui.GetSystemMenu(hwnd, False)
        win32gui.AppendMenu(hmenu, win32con.MF_SEPARATOR, 5, '')
        win32gui.AppendMenu(hmenu, win32con.MF_STRING, self.custom_menu_id, 'Custom menu text')
...

    def nativeEvent(self, eventType, message):
        retval, result = super(MainWindow, self).nativeEvent(eventType, message)

        # handle the click on the title bar
        try:
            msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG.from_address(message.__int__())
        except:
            msg = None

        if eventType == "windows_generic_MSG" and msg is not None:
            if msg.message == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
                # bonus - here's how to handle the left click
                pass

            if msg.message == WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                if msg.wParam == self.custom_menu_id:
                   # do me now!
                   return True, 0

        return retval, result
```

Comment: попробовал запустить ваш код в отдельном окне, без моего кода. В целом запускается и при нажатии на иконку главного окна открывается меню с добавленным пунктом. Только в коде не определены некоторые переменные и без них код не работает (запускал код закомментив их). Что такое ctypes, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN и WM_SYSCOMMAND и откуда их брать? Как мне обработать момент, чтобы при нажатии на новый пункт в меню открывалось диалоговое окно?

Answer (score 1):

Я покажу вам, один из вариантов, как создать пользовательскую панель заголовка.
а выглядит это примерно так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, second_window):
        second_window.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        second_window.setEnabled(True)
        second_window.resize(320, 240)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(second_window.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        second_window.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        second_window.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(320, 240))
        second_window.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(320, 240))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        second_window.setFont(font)
        second_window.setStyleSheet("")
        second_window.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(second_window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        second_window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(second_window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(second_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, second_window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        second_window.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", 
            """
            <html><head/><body>
            <p>
              <span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-style:italic; 
                color:#000000;\">Версия приложения 0.1. Находится в тестировании, 
                может использоваться в качестве готовой версии приложения.
              </span>
            </p>
            <p align=\"center\">
              <img src=\"boy4.png\"/>
            </p>
            <p align=\"center\">
              <span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-style:italic; 
                color:#000000;\">Copyright © 
              </span>
              <a href=\"https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/539485/\">
                <span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-weight:600; 
                  text-decoration: underline; color:#0000ff;\">Игорь Ищенко
                </span>
              </a><br>
              <a href=\"https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496443/\">
                <span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-weight:600; 
                  color:#ff0000;\">???
                </span> 
              </a>
              <span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-style:italic; 
                color:#000000;\">. ← Работу можно заказать по этому адресу.
              </span>
            </p>
            </body></html>
            """))
        

class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_SecondWindow): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        

class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal(object)
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)
        self._pos = QPoint(0, 0)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(Label, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        self.clicked.emit(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()) +  QPoint(15, 15))


class TitleBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.frameTitle = QFrame()
        self.frameTitle.setFrameStyle(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frameTitle.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.frameTitle.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        colorFrame = self.palette()
        colorFrame.setColor(QPalette.Background, Qt.yellow)        
        self.frameTitle.setPalette(colorFrame)

        self.labelIcon = Label(self)      
        self.labelIcon.setPixmap(QPixmap("icono.png").scaled(
            18, 18, 
            Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        )
        self.labelIcon.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelIcon.setToolTip("Icon")
        self.labelIcon.setFixedWidth(32)
        self.labelIcon.setFixedHeight(24)
        
        self.labelTitle = QLabel("Чтение БКУ")
        self.labelTitle.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        font_title = self.font()
        font_title.setPointSize(14)        
        self.labelTitle.setFont(font_title)
        self.labelTitle.setToolTip("Hазвание")

        buttonMinimize = QToolButton()
        buttonMinimize.setToolTip("Minimize")
        buttonMinimize.setIconSize(QSize(38, 25))
        buttonMinimize.setAutoRaise(True)
        buttonMinimize.setIcon(
            QApplication.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TitleBarMinButton))
        buttonMinimize.clicked.connect(self._minimize)
        
        self.buttonMaxRes = QToolButton()
        self.buttonMaxRes.setToolTip("Maximizar")
        self.buttonMaxRes.setIconSize(QSize(38, 25))
        self.buttonMaxRes.setAutoRaise(True)
        self.buttonMaxRes.setIcon(
            QApplication.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TitleBarMaxButton))
        self.buttonMaxRes.clicked.connect(self._maximize_restore)
        
        buttonClose = QToolButton()
        buttonClose.setToolTip("Закрыть")
        buttonClose.setIconSize(QSize(38, 25))
        buttonClose.setAutoRaise(True)
        buttonClose.setIcon(
            QApplication.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TitleBarCloseButton))
        buttonClose.clicked.connect(self._close)

        layoutH = QHBoxLayout(self.frameTitle)
        layoutH.setSpacing(0)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.labelIcon)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.labelTitle)
        layoutH.addWidget(buttonMinimize)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.buttonMaxRes)
        layoutH.addWidget(buttonClose)
        layoutH.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        main_layoutH = QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_layoutH.addWidget(self.frameTitle)
        main_layoutH.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.pressing = False

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(TitleBar, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.frameTitle.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width())
        self.labelTitle.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width() - 62)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end - self.start
            self.parent.setGeometry(
                self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).x(),
                self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).y(),
                self.parent.width(), self.parent.height()
            )
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if self.parent.isMaximized():
                self.parent.showNormal()
                self.buttonMaxRes.setIcon(
                    QApplication.style().standardIcon(
                        QStyle.SP_TitleBarMaxButton)
                )
                self.buttonMaxRes.setToolTip("Maximizar")
            else:
                self.parent.showMaximized()
                self.buttonMaxRes.setIcon(
                    QApplication.style().standardIcon(
                        QStyle.SP_TitleBarNormalButton)
                )
                self.buttonMaxRes.setToolTip("Restaurar")

    def _minimize(self):
        self.parent.showMinimized()

    def _maximize_restore(self):
        if self.parent.isMaximized():
            self.parent.showNormal()
            self.buttonMaxRes.setIcon(QApplication.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TitleBarMaxButton))
            self.buttonMaxRes.setToolTip("Увеличить")
        else:
            self.parent.showMaximized()
            self.buttonMaxRes.setIcon(QApplication.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TitleBarNormalButton))
            self.buttonMaxRes.setToolTip("Восстановление")

    def _close(self):
        self.parent.close()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):                     
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint) # !!!
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 400)
        self.pressing = False
        
        self.titleBar = TitleBar(self)         
        self.titleBar.labelIcon.clicked.connect(self.labelIcon_clicked)
        
        self.layout_main_window = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_main_window.addWidget(self.titleBar)
        self.layout_main_window.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.initUI()
        self.table.setFocus()
        
        self.context_menu = QMenu(self)
        self.init_menu()

    def init_menu(self):
        self.context_menu.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.context_menu.setWindowFlags(
            self.context_menu.windowFlags() | 
            Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.NoDropShadowWindowHint)

        action = self.context_menu.addAction('меню about', self.create_window)
        action = self.context_menu.addAction(
            QIcon("img/readMe.png"), '&About', self.about_qt)
        self.context_menu.addSeparator()
        action = self.context_menu.addAction(
            QIcon("img/exit.png"), "&Quit", self.close)
        
    def labelIcon_clicked(self, pos):
        self.context_menu.exec_(pos)

    def initUI(self):
        # конфигурация верхней панели инструментов
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addStretch(1)
        self.btn_start_reading = QPushButton("Считать")
        self.btn_download_from_file = QPushButton("Загрузить из файла")
        self.btn_save_to_file = QPushButton("Экспорт")
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_start_reading)
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_download_from_file)
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_save_to_file)
        self.layout_main_window.addLayout(self.layout_toolbar_buttons)

        # конфигурация таблицы
        self.layout_table = QHBoxLayout()
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(9)
        self.table.setRowCount(13500)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['№', 'Дата и время', 'БКУ', 'КЛ', 'АУ', 'Канал', 
            'Код события', 'Доп. параметр', 'Описание'])
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        for col in range(8):
            self.table.setColumnWidth(col, 130)
        self.layout_table.addWidget(self.table)
        self.layout_main_window.addLayout(self.layout_table)

    def about_qt(self):
        # О Qt
        QApplication.instance().aboutQt()

    def create_window(self):
        self.second_window = SecondWindow(self)
        self.second_window.show()
        

Style = """
QMenu {
    background-color: rgba(64, 224, 208, 220);
    border: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
QMenu::item {
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 8px 48px 8px 36px;       
    background-color: transparent;
}
QMenu::item:selected {
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(32, 178, 170, 232);
}
QMenu::item:disabled {
    background-color: transparent;
}
QMenu::icon {
    left: 15px;
}
QMenu::separator {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: rgb(232, 236, 255);
}
"""
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Style)
    w = MainWindow()     
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно переопределить системное меню при помощи `setWindowFlag()`:

```
self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint, False)
help_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Справка')
about_action = QAction('О программе', self)
about_action.triggered.connect(self.show_about_dialog)
help_menu.addAction(about_action)
```

Ну и соответственно окошко:

```
def show_about_dialog(self):
        dialog = QDialog(self)
        dialog.setWindowTitle('О программе')
        layout = QVBoxLayout(dialog)
        label = QLabel('Бла бла бла')
        layout.addWidget(label)
        button = QPushButton('OK')
        button.clicked.connect(dialog.accept)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        dialog.exec_()
```

---

**Update**

Попробуйте добавить:

```
self.windowIconChanged.connect(self.handle_window_icon_changed)
```

и создать:

```
def handle_window_icon_changed(self):
        if self.windowIcon():
            self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint, True)
        else:
            self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint, False)
```

Comment: это немного не то, чего бы я хотел. Теперь вверху окна всегда висит меню "справка". А я хотел бы, чтобы этот пункт появлялся только при нажатии на иконку главного окна.

Comment: попробовал второй вариант, но судя по всему ничего не происходит, всплывающее меню никак не меняется.

Answer (score 0):

> Перевод [оригинального ответа Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393597/how-to-create-a-menu-bar-in-a-qmainwindow) для русскоязычного сообщества с небольшим комментарием от меня.

Это меню не определяется — оно действительно стандартно для всех окон и предполагает основные действия с расположением окна и его статусом. В вашем случае подойдёт меню сверху, реализуемое с помощью компонента QMenuBar. [image: изображение QMenuBar].

Чтобы создать кнопку в панели меню, нужно задать ей название. Кроме того, кнопки и действия принадлежат не Qt, поэтому вам нужно задать родительский объект для них или сохранить их куда-то, чтобы они не были удалены сборщиком мусора. Вот пример:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        menubar = self.menuBar()  # создаём меню
        menu = QMenu('Справка', self) # заголовок и родительский объект
        action = QAction('О программе', self) # title and parent
        action.triggered.connect(self.do_something)  # привязка к функции при нажатии на кнопку
        menu.addAction(action)
        menubar.addMenu(menu)
```

И есть и более простой способ добиться того же результата, добавляя меню и действия непосредственно через методы объектов, примерно так:

```py
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        menu = menubar.addMenu('Справка')
        action = menu.addAction("О программе")
        action.triggered.connect(self.do_something)
```

Comment: У меня есть аналогичная программа, реализованная на C#, и там этот пункn в меню, всплывающем при нажатии на иконку, успешно добавлен. Хотелось бы добиться того же на PyQT5.

Comment: @ИгорьИщенко, а вот это уже другая проблема. Приложите код к вопросу и переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы в нём было понятно, какой участок кода на C# вы хотите переписать на Python. Это будет гораздо конкретнее.

Comment: к сожалению у меня нет исходного кода, я только видел саму программу.

Comment: я нашел исходный код, приложил его в обновленном вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить пункт о программе  в PyQt5, вы можно заюзать метод menuBar() объекта QMainWindow. Сначала задаем экземпляр класса QAction, который будет отвечать за пункт меню о программе, затем добавляем его к объекту QMenu, а затем добавим этот QMenu к объекту menuBar().
По коду примерно так, но надо будет уже доделать под себя

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # ... Ваш код ...
        
        # добавляем меню
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        about_action = QAction("О программе", self)
        about_action.triggered.connect(self.about_program)
        file_menu = menubar.addMenu("&Файл")
        file_menu.addAction(about_action)

    def about_program(self):
        # здесь может быть код для отображения диалогового окна с информацией о программе
        pass
```

Comment: мне нужно не создать новую панель меню, а добавить пункт в меню, которое открывается при нажатии на иконку главного окна